# Distribute n balls across m bags when bags are not empty to get the same sizes

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Thinking about the best solution of the next problem.

Suppose we have m bags where $n_1, n_2, ..., n_m$ balls are already laid.

We need to distribute new n balls across these bags to get almost the same sizes in each bag, i.e. sizes are allowed to differ not more than by $1$.

Like if we have bags with $1, 2, 3$ balls and want to add $2$ other balls then we can add one to the first bag and one to the second (or to the first again). We'll get $3, 2, 3$ or $2, 3, 3$ distribution then.

The solution I see:

> > **1.** Order bags by balls count - O(m$log$m)
> >
> > **2.** *Iteratively*: Find bags with the same sizes, fill them up to the next size threshold, repeat for new threshold.
> >     Like if we need to fill $1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 6$ bags with 10 balls we
> >
> > a) On the first iteration add $3, 3$ to the first two bags,
> >
> > b) On the second iteration add  $1, 1, 1, 1$ to the first four bags
> >
> > c) And we are done.

Suppose, we have pretty many balls to distribute ($n \gt \gt m$).

Then we'll need m steps to find all thresholds, and O($m^2$) to fill them all.

So, the algorithm is quadratic by the bags count.

The question is if there's more optional algorithm for that problem.

Answer (score 0):

We assume that balls are identical and bags are distinct. The idea is non-algorithmic, it might help.

Let $N=n+n_1+n_2+\dots +n_m$. Then every box contains at least $\lfloor \frac{N}{m} \rfloor$ balls. We are left with $r:=N-\lfloor \frac{N}{m} \rfloor$ balls that can be distributed in $\binom{m}{r}$ ways.

Comment: Sorry, I am not following your idea. The initial values in the boxes are not supposed to be distributed uniformly. So, the first can contain zero boxes and the second - ten. We also cannot move balls from one bag to another. It means that your sentence about N/m balls in each bag is incorrect.

Comment: Finally, each box contains either $\lfloor \frac{N}{m} \rfloor$ or $\lfloor \frac{N}{m} \rfloor +1$ balls. As the first step, we fill $i$ th box with $\lfloor \frac{N}{m} \rfloor -n_i$ balls for all $i$, so that each box contains $\lfloor \frac{N}{m} \rfloor$ balls. We are left with $r:=N-\lfloor \frac{N}{m} \rfloor$ balls, that can be distributed in $\binom{m}{r}$ ways. I hope this clarifies.